# Proving a trigonometric inequality $(1-\sin a)x^2 -2x\cos a + 1+ \sin a \ge 0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$(1-\sin (a))x^2 -2x\cos(a) + 1+ \sin( a) \ge 0$, where $a,x$ are any two real constants.

Any suggestions on how to prove this ? I tried playing with it, but nothing useful came out.

Comment: Solved it, thanks !

Comment: How have you solved it?

Comment: Uh..My solution is probably 10 times longer than yours, so it'd be kinda bothersome to lay all the calculations here, the final form I've arrived at looks like this : $[(x+1)sin(a/2)+(x-1)cos(a/2))]^2$

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Weierstrass substitution?

Comment: Used it before I found a different solution, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What's the source of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another way, by AM-GM
$$(1-\sin a) x^2 + (1+\sin a) \ge 2\sqrt[]{(1-\sin^2 a)x^2}= 2\lvert x \cos a \rvert$$

Comment: Wow this was really cool ! Thanks a lot @Macavity gotta hand it to you

Comment: simple and neat solution!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$x^2(1-\sin a)-2x\cos a+(1+\sin a)=y$$

$$\iff x^2(1-\sin a)-2x\cos a+(1+\sin a)-y=0$$

For real $x,$

$$(2\cos a)^2-4(1-\sin a)(1+\sin a-y)\ge0$$

As $\displaystyle\cos^2a=(1-\sin a)(1+\sin a)$ and $\displaystyle4(1-\sin a)\ge0, $

$\displaystyle(1+\sin a)-(1+\sin a-y)\ge0\iff y\ge0$

Answer (score 1):

If $1-\sin a=0$, then $\sin a=1$ and $\cos a=0$ so that the problem is trivial. If $1-\sin a\neq 0$, then the given expression is a polynomial of the form $dx^2+bx+c$ where $b^2=4dc$. So the polynomial factors into $d\left(x+\frac{b}{2d}\right)^2\geq 0$ (note that in this case $d=1-\sin a\geq 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Set $\sin a=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos a=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, t=\tan(a/2)$, then the original inequality becomes:

$$\frac{(1 + t - x +  tx)^2}{ (1 + t^2)}\ge 0$$

Which obviously holds.

Comment: I'm gonna settle with this, thanks a lot @mike +1

Answer (score 1):

## $\cos^2 a = 1-\sin^2a=(1+\sin a)(1-\sin a)$

## $1+\sin a = \frac {\cos^2 a}{1-\sin a}$

Substituting this value in the equation --

## $(1-\sin a)x^2 -2x\cos(a) + [1+ \sin( a)]  $

## =$(1-\sin a)x^2 -2x\cos(a) + \frac {\cos^2 a}{1-\sin a}  $

## =$[x \root  \of {1-\sin a} - \frac {\cos a}{\root \of {1-\sin a}}  ]^2$

## $\ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

This is a degree 2 polynomial in $x$ with discriminant proportional to $(\cos a)^2 - (1-\sin a)(1+\sin a) = 0$, hence it keeps a constant sign.